# Agra to Jaipur - How to hire a taxi / driver?

Tags: india, taxis, agra, jaipur

In a few weeks we’ll be travelling to India. We’ll stay one night in Agra, visit the Taj and then want to travel to Jaipur by taxi, leaving Agra around noon. We want to stop on route to see some sights, and stay in Jaipur.

We’ve used Ola cabs and Uber before within cities, but that might not be the best option in this case.

What would be the best way to find a driver?

Update: we ended up getting a taxi from the hotel we were staying. As we were at the Taj in the early morning, we had plenty of time to visit both Fatephur Sikri and the baoli. A train ride would have been cheaper, but we’re really happy with the choice we made as the boali was very impressive.

Comment: It took us a day to get from Agra to Jaipur.  We were at the Taj just after sunrise and stopped at the tomb of Akhbar the Great then Fatepur Sikri.  Even without stopping I doubt you'd get to Jaipur for noon.

Comment: Our goal is not to arrive in Jaipur at noon, but to do exactly as you describe. Namely to visit the Taj in the morning, then visit Fatepur Sikri and end the day in Jaipur (no time specified).
How did you plan it, and how did you travel? Would you recommend it?

Comment: It was a few years ago.  We used an agency, agreed an itinerary with them and they organised the hotels, provided a driver for two weeks and guides at the sites we were visiting.  It was a fantastic two weeks and the sites, sights and people were amazing.  We didn't have to worry about organising anything while we were there, which made for an easy time but it's often the things that aren't easy that make a visit more memorable.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, hope we’ll have just as nice a trip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding a taxi driver is rarely a problem in India, in fact it's almost the opposite, the "Golden Triangle" of Delhi-Agra-Jaipur is a *very* popular tourist route and you'll be besieged with offers of rides the instant you step out of the train station or your hotel.

The hard part is, of course, choosing one. Locals work off trusted recommendations but as a tourist you're unlikely to have any.  Any travel agency, hotel or guesthouse can also arrange one for you, at a sizable commission of course.

But looks like Uber India has a possible solution for you: I've never tried this myself, but apparently they now offer [Uber Intercity](https://www.uber.com/in/en/ride/intercity/) for "outstation" taxis.  Definitely worth a shot?

Finally, it's been a while since I've been in these parts, but Agra to Jaipur in half a day including stops for sights sounds ambitious? Google Maps says it's 4:30 and given the conditions on most Indian highways even that sounds optimistic.

Comment: Thank you very much!
This day would be the busiest on our itinerary, which was why I’m looking to see if it is viable. Our alternative is taking the train and not visiting Fatepur Sikri.

Comment: @FreekSanders Glad I could help, please accept the answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 4):

Book a train to Jaipur from Agra cantt or Tundla railway station which takes approximately 3 and half hours.

Book according to your availability. Multiple trains are available in noon.

This will save money, and you would have a peaceful taj visit, instead always thinking in mind of the way ahead.

Answer (score 2):

The best method to find a Taxi / Driver is to book through a travel agency. Search your requirements on Google, open maps, and look for ones with good ratings.

Avoid booking through MMT or other OTA's as their prices are significantly High.

Also, Avoid using Ola or Uber, as they are good and cheap options only for traveling within the city.